"Deterministic" examples of Schrodinger operators with pure point spectrum
I'm looking at self-adjoint Schrodinger operators $-\Delta + V$ defined on $\mathbb R$. I'm aware of a few results which are of the form "take this parameterised family of operators $H_\alpha$ satisfying these conditions, then for almost all $\alpha$, the spectrum of $H_\alpha$ is pure point". For example, by Example 6.1 in https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0348-8623-9_13, if $(q_n)$ are iid random variables (it's not specified in the paper, but I think these should be on a complete probability space $\Omega$), $f \ge 0$ continuous is supported on $[-1/2, 1/2]$ and has $|f(x)| \ge 1$ for $x$ near $0$, then the operator:
$$H_\omega = -\Delta + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty q_n(\omega) f(x - n)$$
has pure point spectrum for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$.
This is not quite enough for my purposes. I am specifically looking for the sequence $(q_n(\omega))$ to be some Turing computable sequence of real numbers. I only need one sequence, nothing too fancy. Of course, giving the infinite product measure to $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb N}$, a sequence is computable with probability zero. If I try to put a probability measure on the space of computable sequences, off the top of my head I will have issues with independence and even identical distribution.
I am aware of the result that if $V$ is bounded below and $V(x) \to \infty$ as $|x| \to \infty$, then $-\Delta + V$ has purely discrete spectrum. I haven't quite been able to get the result I want out of this, though. I am also aware of a result of Weidmann (Theorem 9.36 in https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-schroe/schroe.pdf) which gives pure point spectrum below $0$ if $V$ is integrable in a weak sense, but luckily (/j) I quickly need to become concerned about spectral type around $0$ where we might get a transition between pure point and absolutely continuous spectrum. Are there any "deterministic" criterion for the spectrum of $-\Delta + V$ being pure point, perhaps even just in a particular region, involving fairly explicit conditions on $V$, or is there a way I can cajole these probabilistic results into giving what I want?

got a bit tunnel visioned trying to get a specific construction to work, the Weidmann result (in combination with a result in "Operators with Singular Continuous Spectrum V") does suffice for my purposes with a modified construction. still interested if there's any nice results though.
